# Rails Accessing Polymorphic Data from a Relation

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have following models in a Rails application.

```
class Address < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :addressable, :polymorphic => true
end

class Client < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :address, :as => :addressable, dependent: :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :address, :allow_destroy => true

  has_many :invoices
end

class Invoice < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :client
end
```

While I am able to retrieve the client name using

```
@invoice.client.name
```

I am not able to retrieve the address information in the similar manner.

How do I retrieve the address attributes in the view for invoice?

Comment: @invoice.client.address

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**@invoice.client.address** that is the aswer. But i recommend you follow the Law of Demeter using the method **delegate**

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_Demeter
http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Module.html#method-i-delegate

Basically the idea is that you can do this: @invoice.client.address_street o better @invoice.client_address_street

Comment: Thank you. I had tried that and it did not work. Now I found the issue to be in the seed data I created, in which the client was not linked to an address. Anyway, I got to familiarize the Law of Demeter, and I have implemented that. Thanks!